# image selection from a different webpage

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, imagemagick

Iam desghning glitter text generating website ..where users can select glitters[images] to put it as a text background .. to desighn this iam using the code below...

```
<ul class="greybox">
        <label style="font-family: NewCenturySchlbk;">
<input type="radio" name="image" value=" Flame-04-june.gif"/> <img src="     Flame-04-june.gif" alt="thumbs up">
 </label>
  </ul>   

 <ul class="greybox">
         <label style="font-family: Helvetica;">
  <input type="radio" name="image" value=" Flame-05-june.gif"/> <img src="     Flame-05-june.gif" alt="thumbs up">
</label>

</ul>
```

the above code gives an option for users to select one of the images ...user can select image by checking radio button selcted image will be posted to the form specified..code works fine... but its increasing the loading time of the homepage,bcos i have added more then 400 images .... i know this can be reduced by giving an option to click on the link which opens a pop up window where all the images are listed and the user can select one of the images and the selected image should be posted to the form....but how to do desghn  the code where the selected image from the popup windows to post it to the "form" ...

Comment: Why are you using multiple `<ul>`s for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all start cleaning up your code:

```
<style>
  .greybox label { font-family: NewCenturySchlbk; }
</style>

<ul class="greybox">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="image" value=" Flame-04-june.gif"/> <img src="Flame-04-june.gif" alt="thumbs up">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="image" value=" Flame-05-june.gif"/> <img src="Flame-05-june.gif" alt="thumbs up">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Loading 400 images is a lot and will slow it down. Not sure what you mean by a pop-up, but why don't you have a search or paging function? 400 is also a lot to scroll down to.

Also look at the filesizes of the images, try to compress them and the page will also load faster.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,,,,400 images what i have mentioned are very small sized images all the images will be dispalyed in single page itself so that user do not have to scroll down at all...pop up windows  means ,,, i will just put a link some thing like " select images" when the user clicks on the "select images" it should open a new pop up window or or different webpage ,where all the images will be listed .User can select any one of the images by checking the radio button ,many website have already used this concept please check cooltext.com ..iam trying to desighn exactly similar to that.

Comment: I would recommend you to not use a pop-up, that won't help for usability and then the pop-up will load very low. Rather categorize and have several pages for example, or use pagination.
Eventhough the image sizes might be small, it doesn't mean that the file size cannot be improved. Have a look at this tool from Yahoo: http://smush.it/